# Is it possible to use Jquery Validation Plugin with a bootstrap modal(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a master page with a form element:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">             
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

In my child pages I have several bootstrap modals and in those modals I would like to be able to validate that information before closing the modal.

In most cases I am building those modals dynamically.

I've tried 2 different approaches so far without any success:

1. `$("#form1").validate();`
2. `$("#frmUserModal").validate();` I then added the form tag to the modal-body of my modal.

Ex:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form id="frmUserModal" >
      <div class="form-group">...controls...</div>
   </form>
</div>
```

In the second case I examined the `HTML` the second form element is never rendered. (I assume because you can't nest form elements).  However why is my validation not executing off the main form, or how can I go about validating these modals?

Comment: You can not have 2 nested form elements. It's not a valid HTML markup, try removing the "frmUserModal" form

Comment: I originally didn't have 2 form elements and I still have the same issue.

Comment: What do you mean when you said you've tried with no success? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, I am also not seeing any validation occur.

Comment: Did you try $("#frmUserModal").valid();? it should return true if the form is valid and false otherwise

Comment: It comes back as Undefined

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding another ContentPlaceHolder.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">             
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContentPost" runat="server">             
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

I then added my validation to that placeholder.  However there still has to be a better way to handle this validation.  I still have to use $("#form1").validate(); 
Since I have many forms calling many more modals I really will have to be diligent on resetting the form validation. 
I really wish I could validate on a div element.